# File content is blank, when raw file downloaded from gitlab using gitlab api

Tags: java, spring-boot, angular8, gitlab-api

Using GitLab Api, I am able to download the raw file and writing to a new file using Angular8 functionality. After writing when I am extracting that file it's showing blank content. Please suggest I have a requirement for download of zip file from gitlab repository in a file explorer.  Below api i have used.

```
Get raw file from repository
GET /projects/:id/repository/files/:file_path/raw

curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>"
```

"https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/13083/repository/files/app%2Fmodels%2Fkey%2Erb/raw?ref=master"

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Please find above api i have used for downloading file.